# angularjs - can not find the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 js files in different directories for each module. if i start my app, i get the error, that the controller `SubAppCtrl` cannot be found ... can anyone tell me, why do i get this error message?

Code in mainAPP:

```
var myModule = angular.module('mainAPP', ['subAPP']); 

myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { $routeProvider.when('/test', {templateUrl: 'components/test/test-list.html', controller: SubAppCtrl});}]);
```

Code in subAPP:

```
var myapp = angular.module('subAPP', []); 

myapp.controller('SubAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$translate', function ($scope, $rootScope, $translate){ .... ]);
```

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mainAPP" lang="en">
<head>
...
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="components/test/subAPP.js"></script>
  <script src="js/mainAPP.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your wrapper, or header? please post it

Comment: hello i have updated the posting ... that's all i have ... if there is something is missing, please tell me what else i need

Comment: And this is why you DON'T put scripts in your header.

Comment: how else should i do it? sorry for the question, but angularjs is a new topic for me

Comment: I personally put my scripts in to `<head>` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainApp` should read

```
var myModule = angular.module('mainAPP', ['subAPP']); 

myModule.config([
        /******/ '$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/test', {
                templateUrl: 'components/test/test-list.html',
                controller: 'SubAppCtrl'
            });
        }
]);
```

note quotes around the controller name.